# How do I report a spam/fake radio station in the list of iTunes internet radio?

Tags: itunes, spam, itunes-radio

This radio station doesn't play and is just an advertisement for another service. It doesn't play any music. It only asks you to visit their web site. How do I report it?

> Chillout Beats    Live365 - Epic Chillout - flavored with downtempo, lounge, and a splash of light trance-house-dance.     Relaxing, inspirational, and motivational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://apple.com/feedback or contact Apple Support for the iTunes store to register that opinion / information about their music service.

Comment: Also @chloe - thanks for taking the time to help clean up bad actors. I'm sure there are several stations that exist outside the intent to provide entertainment and instead are money grabs.